# how to reduce the size of 3D pie Graph

Tags: pchart

i need to decrease the size of 3D pie Graph .i have changed $Radius=100 into $Radius=50 in pChart.class but not happening the size of graph .i am following the link

http://pchart.sourceforge.net/documentation.php?topic=exemple11

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
// Pie chart with radius of 100
$picture->drawPieGraph($DataSet->GetData(), $DataSet->GetDataDescription(), 150, 150, 100, PIE_PERCENTAGE);

// Pie chart with radius of 50
$picture->drawPieGraph($DataSet->GetData(), $DataSet->GetDataDescription(), 150, 150, 50, PIE_PERCENTAGE);
```